# Cython equivalent for "using Time = cppClassDefinition<withT>"

Tags: c++, cython, cythonize

I'm trying to wrap a cpp application and the source code contains the following in a header file

```
using Time = cppClassDefinition<withT>

...

void setDefaultTime(Time x)
```

What would be the Cython equivalent for this?

I've tried

```
cdef extern from "headerfile.h" namespace "ns":
    ctypedef cppClassDefinition<withT> Time
```

to no success. Although Cython does not complain at this step, it throws a compilation error when I try to use the function `setDefaultTime(1.0)`. The error states "Cannot assign type 'double' to 'Time'. In the CPP code however, this seems to be working fine.

I've also tried

```
cdef extern from "headerfile.h" namespace "ns":
    cdef cppclass Time:
        pass
```

and that also failed. Any suggestions? Is this possible using Cython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest in the question, you should be able to use use

```
ctypedef cppClassDefinition[withT] Time
```

since `using ... = ...` in this context is equivalent to a `typedef`. (Note the change to square brackets compared to the code in your question).

I believe the problem is instead with your attempt to do `setDefaultTime(1.0)`. Cython has no way of knowing that `double` can be converted to `Time` and there isn't any way of telling it about implicit C++ conversions.

The easiest way round this is to just tell Cython that the function signature is

```
void setDefaultTime(double x)
```

(You can leave the C++ signature as is). This will satisfy Cython, and then the C++ code it generates should end up working correctly provided that `double` can be implicitly converted to `Time` (as the question implies)